# Using ZXing natively to get information of product using barcode number

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am developing an app which uses barcode to get the product information of food items after scanning the barcode.

I don't want the user to install ZXing barcode app separately so I embedded the ZXing code into my project.

So I was able to obtain the barcode ID number. 
But I do not know how to get the product information like name, manufacturer, price etc from the number using ZXing code. Since I am somewhat new to android, the ZXing code of retrieving product information is difficult for me.

So I need the basic steps on how to retrieve product information from the barcode Id.

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zxing project does not provide you any information about the manufacturer of the product. You have to do it on your own. Barcode can be read using ZXing and you have to check the corresponding number related to the product which is pre-configured in your database.

Comment: oh ok..Can you give me an idea of how to do it? I searched a lot in google..but couldn't find any useful information..Can you help me with a sample code or links to sample code..?

Comment: u save the list of numbers in your database in the webserver and compare the barcode that u have read from the zxing with each of them

Comment: Hi @SeshuVinay i want to get product information from barcode number. Does it required any paid webserver which will provide me webservices for getting product information from barcode. I am  android developer and i don't have so much knowledge about servers. So plz guide me how can i get product information from barcode number.

Comment: You don't need any server to read barcodes. You could either use Zxing's official app to read barcode using Intent or create your own.

Answer (score 2):

The project does not provide any production information. It's up to you to obtain that.

Comment: ok..thank you very much for the info..Can you give me an idea of how to do it? I searched a lot in google..but couldn't find any useful information..Can you help me with a sample code or links to sample code..?